Does the species number of microorganisms in the genital tract significantly increase through an indirect sexual tree?
Let's say:

The indirect sexual relationship tree (assuming condoms are not used) can be huge.

The A at the tree end had only one sex partner B for a period (e.g. a few months and thus joined the huge tree).

STI tests get negative results for A and B, so you can think their immune systems work fine.


Does indirect contact significantly increase the species number in A's genital tract? For example, compared to a typical species number N, from N to 100N or even more if the tree is large enough (there is an upbound of course). Or does the species number change slightly due to some inherent biological limit in the genital tract?
Considering there are many microorganism species (most of which could be viruses) in the human genital tract -- known and unknown, unique to individuals, and common in humans, this is more of a statistical issue.
I consulted someone who seems to be a scholar, she says:

I think the species number would be almost the same -- unless the original number in A is fairly small -- for example, several only.

Are there any known studies or discussions on this topic? I tried search engines but most research studies focus on specific microbial species.

As you have been told previously, one question per post. Please add your references too.

@JiminyCricket. Sorry. The question is edited. As this is a suspicion, I do not have a specific link. Is this allowed? (I tried search engines but found almost nothing on this problem.)

The question has numerous potential problems and I'd suggest it was badly worded.
The specific issue is the way the "non-pathogenic microbiome" is worded by isolating it from STDs in the face of re-emergent and endemic infections. The microbe more broadly could play a protective role in other infections, e.g. UTIs, or cervical cancer (waving my arms about a bit). So it certainly worthy.
If the OPs question was a clinical study it would encounter opposition from infectious disease specialists on an ethics panel, i.e. they would possibly reject the study as it is currently written:

Chlamydia and gonorrhea are endemic in the USA (CDC report) and the largest source of preventable infertility on earth, for example even in China (Liu et al 2022).
Both infections have complex incubation periods, therefore a patient can be infected without it showing on a diagnostic test; even with the best techniques (NHS, UK, e.g. Reyes-Lacalle 2022).
Diagnosis efficacy is variable depending on the underlying technique: MAb based, PCR and culture. Hence again a patient can be infected but the infection isn't detected (Hiller et al, 2021).
Undetected infections significantly risk female infertility (for example Tsevat et al. 2017)

To summarise: the problem with the OP's question is that this might be inferring that a diverse microbe offers STD protection (unlikely). If it was re-focused it could be a really good question.

The OP's question is so badly worded that a completely opposite interpretation is also possible: the worry that as-yet-unknown microbes (not including known STI-associated pathogens) may exist in such numbers in the "indirect sexual tree" as to threaten anyone entering this so-named tree with an increased chance of cancer from a multiplicity of unknown but pathogenic organisms. As such, the question is so poorly defined that the answer you provided may not be the answer the OP is looking for at all. That's why asking for clarification in comments before answering is so helpful.

(Although if your interpretation is the one the OP meant, it is a valuable answer, though it doesn't address the hypothetical: that in the reproductive tract there may exist untold numbers of pathogens capable of causing cancers.)

@anongoodnurse Your first interpretation of my question is what I meant to ask. The key info I want to find is "Is there any biological factor that limits the spice numbers -- especially for viruses". The problem is that I used “diversity,” which usually excludes viruses (I learned this today). So would a question like "Does the species number of microorganisms in the genital tract significantly increase through an indirect sexual tree?" be better? I was told such a question is "nothing of biological interest". Could you please give me some advice?

I had thought of "a diverse microbe offers STD protection" -- I know little about this except for an intuition that "this is unlikely" (especially for viruses).  The interpretation from the first comment here is what I tried to ask. But such a question seems to be "of no value",  Is this because "we have little overall understanding of unknown microorganisms"?
